# no matter what I do, the hair net addon doesn't work (Blender 2.9)

Tags: particles, hair

It doesn't wanna make hair from anything, It always gives me an error. Doesn't matter if its making it from a curve or from a sheet.

Here's the error it gives me after I try to convert from curve

[image]

And I also don't get any results from using sheets, they always give me an error that states "No seams were defined in X". I definately created seams where I wanted on the plane. as you can see down below
[image]

I feel like I'm at the end of my rope with this. Nothing works I followed the tutorials on this to the letter but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This looks like a fault in the code, and may be because of a change in blender’s API since the addon was created.

Answer (score 1):

**HairNet version**
For Blender **2.90.1** you need [HairNet 0.6.3](https://github.com/Jandals/HairNet/releases). Version 0.6.2 is for Blender 2.90.0 (and older) and you will get this "mouse_event" error when you use it in a later version of Blender.

**Sheets**
A common mistake with the sheets is to use a sheet with only 2 "strand edges". The add-on needs at least **3** strand edges to work. Else you get this misleading "no seams" error.

[image: example sheet for hair]

**Additionally**

- make sure that *Location, Scale, and Rotation*  is applied to the hair objects and to the head (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode).
- make sure that you don't have accidentally checked the HairNet option *[_] Emit Hair on Self* when you have a head (sheet and head for example). Check both objects because the setting is not global but stored in the objects.
- select the head/emitter object last (orange selection color)
- the HairNet 0.6.3 (or Blender) has a bug the makes all hair of a random existing hair particles system move down on the z-axis if you add another hair particle system from sheets, curves, etc. You can prevent this if you turn off the previous particle systems in the viewport with the "monitor" icon before you add another one with the add-on.
- don't forget to increase the number of *Strand Steps* (`5`) in the Viewport Display* settings for a better shape
- and to "touch" the created particle guides in *Particle Edit* mode with a minimal strength brush as described in the manual

[image: suzanne got some hair]